# How to send data from iphone to watchkit in swift

Tags: swift, watchkit

I am doing a sample project in which i like to send data from iphone to WatchKit. I have no idea of how to do this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this method in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!,
handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
   reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!)
{
   //define your dictionary
   reply(yourDict)
}
```

Add this anywhere in the Apple Watch Extension:

```
var dict = ["test" : 4] //your dictionary/request to sent to the iPhone
if !WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(dict, reply: { (reply,error) -> Void in
    println("\(reply)") //your reply data as Dictionary
}) {
    println("ERROR")
}
```

The first function will trigger with `WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication` and will reply the dictionary in the `reply` parameter.

**Developer forum:**
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1082689#1082689

Comment: what i trying to do is i am getting data from server, store it in coredata in phoneside then fetch from coredata and send it watchkit.can i done this with above code?

Comment: AFAIK, this to send data from Watch to iPhone, not from iPhone to Watch

Comment: This sends data bothways, just put your data in the reply Dictionary