# How to pass UIImage from iPhone app to Apple Watch app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an iPhone app that captures a UIView as UIImage after 5-10 seconds. Is it possible to pass that UIImage to my Apple Watch app and show it in UIImageView there?

Comment: kindly mention the reason for negative votes..

Comment: My guess would be that you didnt bother googling when there are answers already.

Comment: I googled but found answers related to passing strings etc using NSUserDefaults. And it is not recommended to store images in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. All you need to do is create a `NSDictionary` like:

```
var dict:[NSString : UIImage] = ["image" : yourImage]
```

And then you just use the following methods to communicate between the Apple Watch and the iOS app:
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762906/how-to-send-data-from-iphone-to-watchkit-in-swift/28763677#28763677)

Comment: Bravo Dejan. Thats what i was looking for :)

Comment: Great! You can upvote the LINK answer too, if it was in your help!

Comment: sure. Now iam worried about down votes on my question :)

Comment: Don't worry, will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The answers here are only half correct cause you can't send an UIImage directly!
You need to send your images as NSData like f.e. so:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
              reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
  reply(@{@"image" : UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourUIImage)});
  // JPEG Representation would of course also work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do.

You can pass data using this method

```
- (IBAction)passUserInfo:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"test"]};

    [WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:userInfo reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error){
        if ([replyInfo objectForKey:@"success"]) {
            NSLog(@"Sent your data");
        }
    }];// userinfo must be non-nil
}
```

and you can handle your data in this method.

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{
    UIImage *image = [userInfo objectForKey:@"image"];

    NSDictionary *replyInfo = @{@"success":@"success",@"error":@""};

    reply(replyInfo);
}
```

Otherwise see this Tutorial

[MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole)

Comment: I have seen it already.. It states "Pass a message with an identifier for the message and a NSCoding compliant object as the message itself"
I am afraid that UIImage is not NSCoding complaint, and you have to do some work around to achieve that. So cannot use MMWormhole directly. Thanks for your time Dharmbir