# Passing UIImage from iPhone to Apple Watch results in nil response in watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

My watch needs to request an image from the containing app. In the watch's controller, I have:

```
- (void)getOrgLogo {
    NSString *host = mfaInfo[@"host"];
    NSDictionary *getOrgLogoRequest = @{@"request":@"getOrgLogo", @"host":host};
    [MyInterfaceController openParentApplication:getOrgLogoRequest reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            ...
        } else if (replyInfo == nil) {
            // I am always getting into this block!!!
        } else {
            UIImage *orgLogo = replyInfo[@"orgLogo"];
            if (orgLogo != nil) {
                [self.orgLogoImageView setImage:orgLogo];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

In my main app, I send a request to the server to get the image, then pass the image back to watch:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {
    ...
    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"] isEqualToString:@"getOrgLogo"]) {
        NSString *host = userInfo[@"host"];
        [self handleWatchKitGetOrgLogoRequest:reply withHost:host];
    }
    ...
}

- (void)handleWatchKitGetOrgLogoRequest:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply withHost:(NSString *)host{
    NSMutableDictionary *response = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // A server request to get the image
    [OktaAPIClient getLogoUrlFromHost:host withSuccess:^(UIImage *image) {
        // I'm getting in here - indicating I successfully got the image
        response[@"orgLogo"] = image;
        // I double checked the value of response here - it's not nil!
        reply(response);
    } withFailure:^(UIImage *image) {
        ...
        reply(response);
    }];
}
```

As commented in the code above, I checked the value of response right before I pass it back to watch and confirmed that it contain a value (a UIImage), however in the callback of the watch code, this reply becomes nil. I do not know what happens in the process. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to enable app groups and save the images to a shared folder. This is really good if you are saving multiple images.

Start by enabling app groups under the capabilities tab for both your iphone and apple watch target.

[image: Xcode Capabilities Tab]

Then use this code on the iPhone to save the image.

```
[OktaAPIClient getLogoUrlFromHost:host withSuccess:^(UIImage *image) {
  NSURL *groupURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
    containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.az.simpleSudoku"];

  NSString *sharedFilePath = [groupURL.path 
    stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", @"logo.png"];

  [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:sharedFilePath atomically:YES];

  reply(response);
} withFailure:^(UIImage *image) {
        ...
    reply(response);
}];
```

And this to load that image on the watch.

```
NSURL *groupURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
  containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.az.simpleSudoku"];

NSString *sharedFilePath = [groupURL.path 
  stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", @"logo.png"];

NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];

[myInterfaceImage setImageData:imgData];
```

As long as your app groups are set up correctly, this works very well. I use it to pass sudoku board images back and forth in my app.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiment, it seems that UIImage can't be serialized and sent over to watch from the phone. So I converted the UIImage to NSData, then pass the data to watch, and then it's working fine.

Code in main app's `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *response = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[MyAPIClient getLogoUrlFromHost:host withSuccess:^(UIImage *image) {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [response setObject:imageData forKey:@"orgLogo"];
    reply(response);
} withFailure:^(UIImage *image) {
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [response setObject:imageData forKey:@"orgLogo"];
    reply(response);
}];
```

Code in watch's `openParentApplication:reply:`:

```
NSData *orgLogoData = replyInfo[@"orgLogo"];
if (orgLogoData != nil) {
    [self.orgLogoImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:orgLogoData]];
}
```