# WatchKit: re-fetch changed data in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I got an app that shares data via App Groups and `NSUserDefaults` with the Watch extension.

Everything works fine except for the case that both apps (iOS and Apple Watch app) are running simultaneously. When the user uses one of the apps the changes will be saved to `NSUserDefaults`.

How do I make the other app aware of the changes to `NSUserDefaults` and have it re-fetch the updated data from there?

I know of the `openParentApplication` method for the watch app.

Is there a counterpart for the iOS app to push changes to the watch app?

Comment: Worked with MMWormhole: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118284/communicating-updates-between-iphone-and-watch-with-shareddata