# AVAudioPlayer Control through WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, avaudioplayer

I have a playercontroller view..in this view I am playing selected poem from an array which have collection of my poems.

Now when playing any poem I want to take control to push, play, next, previous and volume control from Apple Watch.

**Here is my code for the iPhone which plays a poem:**

```
if(btnClick == 1) {

    self.lblTitle.text=[titles objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.imgpoem setImage:[poemImages objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSString *songurl=[poemcollection objectAtIndex:0];
    [self playselectdpoem:songurl];
}
```

How can I add this functionality to the WatchKit Extension to control all the things?

Answer (score 0):

To control the iPhone app from the watch, you have to use the `openParentApplication` method. You can take a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762906/how-to-send-data-from-iphone-to-watchkit-in-swift/28763677#28763677), how to implement this method.

The same thing as sending data is to send a signal to the iPhone to do something - in your case, to Pause, Play, Stop ect.